# What's the best way to paginate unsorted and filtered database data via API?

Tags: php, mysql, database, api, pagination

I have been stuck with this problem for a while where I have to fetch data for a home page, like doing multiple queries to filter data by popularity, by most viewed etc. and merging all into a single query using "union". So the query orders them automatically by importance, for example featured goes first then most popular records go next and then most viewed and so on. The data changes from time to time if there is some new record, or some record becomes more popular than the other it might swap the order. However, when I fetch more data via a pagination or "load more", and at the same time some record swapped places with another one in the background, then this record would be shown again in the next page, which makes it redundant since it showed also on the first.

I checked out some twitter API algorithms with since_ID and max_ID, but in my case they don't help since I don't sort them by ID or any specific order, and this is where the complexity arises.

So how exactly am I supposed to deal with redundant data in this case? Has anyone ever had similar experiences?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "load more", you can send the set of ID that is already displayed and consequently exclude them with an additionnal condition in your sql queries " and id not in ([excluded set here]) ".

However with a pagination system, it gets too complex since you have to pass the set of all page visited and you don't control the order of visit, it would turn into a complete mess.
So with pagination I would recommend you simply let your ranking be and eventually cache it for X minutes. So all the users experience the same ranking for a few minutes, and pages never show duplicate content. Also, to improve user experience you can add a visual feedback when the ranking is updated, which provide a sense of interactivity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you suggest to cache only the 1st page or all records? Cuz if only the 1st page, then the same problem would persist, but if I cache the whole records in the query it would affect performance doing a query for like 1000+ records and store them in cache for x minutes.

Comment: You should allow your pagination only over the N first results, 5 to 10 pages for exemples. Other results are "archive". And the cache can store only the id of the articles. 
Edit : a SELECT of 1000 rows every X minutes never took down a sql server ...

Comment: I am not actually worried about the server, but more about user experience. Have to fetch the data via API request in iOS, so when fetching 1000 rows would probably hit the performance, which I am trying to avoid. However I thought about caching them by triggering a background process somehow.

Comment: No you never actually send the 1000 rows to the user.
The user ask for the first page, cache has expired, you fetch the 1000 first ids, you store them in the cache, you fetch X items (X = items per page) from the database using the ids you stored in the cache. You send these X items to the user.

Comment: Perfect, makes sense.